# How do I deserialize nested JSON using Spring restTemplate

Tags: json, spring, resttemplate

I went through the [Consuming a RESTful Web Service guide on the Spring website](http://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/), but it doesn't talk about how to deserialize nested objects. For example, how would I deserialize the location entry in the [sample](http://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/)?

Answer (score 3):

You have to create a domain object for the Location data that is a reference in the top-level Page object. Below is an overly simplified look at the classes. You'll need to properly annotate the objects to serialize/deserialize how you want it to and there are numerous examples on how to do that depending on what markup framework you use.

```
public class Page {
    String id;
    String about;
    ...
    Location location;
    ...
}

public class Location {
    String street;
    String city;
    ...
}
```